# Rundeck - Working with execution logs & Caching

Tags: mysql, rundeck

I have couple of queries-

A. how can i get the execution logs ? The base_report table doesnt provide any reason for failures for jobs. Where are the execution logs stored as my rdlogs dont have the required information? - My rundeck installation uses mysql as db. Kindly help with this requirement.

B. How can we use caching of queries to DB in rundeck ? For eg. Fetching 100 projects and job listing should vary only if there is a change in table else it should fetch from cache?

Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: A. Do you want to get the log from your db only?

Answer (score 2):

Logs for job executions are normally stored at a path relative to your rundeck installation's home directory.

Your home directory should be defined in /etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties, as the value of rdeck.base. It's commonly /var/lib/rundeck.

Eg. Pretending the name of your project is myproject.. execution logs would be at /var/lib/rundeck/logs/rundeck/myproject/job/